# Why does require look for all page objects?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, protractor

My app consists of both angularJS and non-angularJS pages.
Therefore I am using protractor for my e2e tests with cucumber.
I am trying to organize tests using pageObjects.

Folder structure is as follows:

features

```
|_  step_definitions

  |- login.steps.js

gmail.feature
```

pageObject

```
 |- createAccount.js

 |- gmailPage.js
```

protractor.conf.js

**gmail.feature**

```
Feature: Gmail login page

@dev    
Scenario: Create new gmail account
Given I see gmail home page
When I Create an account
Then I should see account creation form
```

**gmailPage.js**

```
'use strict';

var gmail = function () {
this.btnCreateAccount = driver.findElement(By.css('#gmail-create-account'));
};

module.exports = gmail;
```

**createAccount.js**

```
'use strict';

var ca = function () {
this.inpFirstName = driver.findElement(By.css('#firstname'));
};

module.exports = ca;
```

**login.steps.js**

```
'use strict';

var expect = require('chai').expect;
var gmail = new (require('../../pageObject/gmailPage'))();
var ca = new (require('../../pageObject/createAccount'))();

module.exports = function(){
this.Given(/^I see gmail home page$/, function (callback) {
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
          expect(url).to.contain('https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html');
    callback();
  });
});



this.When(/^I Create an account$/, function (callback) {
  gmail.btnCreateAccount.click();
  callback();
});

this.Then(/^I should see account creation form$/, function (callback) {
  callback();
});

};
```

**Problem:**
When I run this test I get `"NoSuchElementError"`, because it is looking for `WebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#firstname"))` present in createAccount.js.

My question is why the webdriver is trying to look for pageObjects in files that are required before it is being called.
Why does this same use case work while using protractor driver?

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate the page objects in your login steps module.

```
'use strict';

var expect = require('chai').expect;
var gmailPage = require('../../pageObject/gmailPage');
var createAccountPage = require('../../pageObject/createAccount');

module.exports = function(){
  var gmail = new gmailPage();
  var ca = new createAccountPage();
  this.Given(/^I see gmail home page$/, function (callback) {
    driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
      expect(url).to.contain('https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html');
      callback();
    });
  });

  this.When(/^I Create an account$/, function (callback) {
    gmail.btnCreateAccount.click();
    callback();
  });

  this.Then(/^I should see account creation form$/, function (callback) {
    callback();
  });

};
```

Comment: You are right, it would work. But, I wanted to understand why this is happening when webdriver - driver is used and not when protractor driver - ptor.

Comment: So you should be more specific in your question.